# Virtual machine GPU passthrough with Windows 7 as host

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

Is it possible to do that with VMware or VirtualBox? I want to have Windows 7 as a host OS and Windows 7 or Windows 10 as a guest OS.

I've seen a few guides, but they all assume I use Linux as a host. Can someone please outline me the general process I should follow to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

as far as I can dig google and other stuff, ATM there is no working way to have any hardware passthrough (other than CPU) with Windows Host, even if on windows virtual box still got the option "--pciattach", any attempt to use that will make virtual machine crash

while under Linux is working - [2 Gaming Rigs, 1 Tower - Virtualized Gaming Build Log](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuJYMCbIbPk) (unraid is a special customized Linux just for that) let's hope this will change for the windows too, sometime soon ... hope die last ^^

Answer (score -4):

It' s possible:

Windows 7 as a HOST with VirtualBox/VMware and you virtualize a other OS (Win7, Win10, GNU/Linux ...) will be the guest.

Process:

1. Install Virtualization software at Host. (VirtualBox with VirtualBox it´s very easy).
2. Create Virtual Machine at Host.
3. Install OS at Virtual Machine, will be the guest.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. What you are describing will simply install a virtual machine, it won't allow for GPU passthrough. [By default, vbox uses "VirtualBox Graphic Adapter"](http://clip2net.com/clip/m485571/249a9-clip-127kb.png?nocache=1), I need virtual machine to be able to access my nvidia directly.

Comment: this question is about "GPU PASSTHROUGH", if you don't know what that is, then please don't answer !